400 Error code when calling Plaid's linkTokenCreate() function
I'm working on integrating Plaid API into an app, and their YouTube videos and quickstart app have been super helpful so far. But I'm stuck at the first step of their flow—generating the link token using the linkTokenCreate() function. All the code is straight from their quickstart app.
According to the docs, I’ve set up the redirect URI (http://localhost:3000/) in the Plaid dashboard and in my .env file. I also checked the Plaid logs, but there's no record of any requests being made.
I am using Postman to make the api call to my app's localhost endpoint to which this createLinkToken() route handler is attached
Here’s my code and the output I’m getting:
const PLAID_CLIENT_ID = process.env.PLAID_CLIENT_ID;
const PLAID_SECRET = process.env.PLAID_SECRET;
const PLAID_ENV = process.env.PLAID_ENV || 'sandbox';
const PLAID_PRODUCTS = (process.env.PLAID_PRODUCTS || Products.Transactions).split(',');
const PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES = (process.env.PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES || 'US').split(',');
const PLAID_REDIRECT_URI = process.env.PLAID_REDIRECT_URI || '';

let ACCESS_TOKEN = null;
let PUBLIC_TOKEN = "";
let ITEM_ID = null;

export const configuration = new Configuration({
    basePath: PlaidEnvironments[PLAID_ENV],
    baseOptions: {
        headers: {
            'PLAID_CLIENT_ID': PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
            'PLAID_SECRET': PLAID_SECRET,
            'Plaid-Version': '2020-09-14'
        },
    },
});
const client = new PlaidApi(configuration);

export const createLinkToken = async (req, res) => {
    const configs = {
        user: {
            client_user_id: 'John Doe' // TODO: Change this to a unique ID representing the end user such as email address or phone number
        },
        client_name: 'HelloWorld',
        products: PLAID_PRODUCTS.map(product => Products[product]),
        country_codes: PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES.map(countryCode => CountryCode[countryCode]),
        language: 'en'
    };

    if (PLAID_REDIRECT_URI !== '') {
        configs.redirect_uri = PLAID_REDIRECT_URI;
    }

    const createTokenResponse = await client.linkTokenCreate(configs);
    prettyPrintResponse(createTokenResponse);
    res.json(createTokenResponse.data);
};

Failed request
I've seen a similar question on StackOverflow and tried everything suggested there, but still no luck.

Welp, turns out I was being an absolute idiot. It was a stupid typo in configuration. Instead of having 'PLAID-CLIENT-ID' I had 'PLAID_CLIENT_ID'
